# Why does not this contract send the tokens to the creator?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, erc-20

I m testing ERC20 token contracts. I could be able to create and get back the tokens in the Ropstan test network.
When I deploy the same contract.sol in the main network my creator address doe not get any tokens back..
when I run the function `transfer`the transaction says  `ERC-20 Token Transfer Failed to complete, check with sender for more information.`

This is the contract address: https://etherscan.io/address/0xbda3d86d96eb05a8965d73cb59b12eeeaf2530be

What could be the reason?

I am using remix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming https://etherscan.io/tx/0xbc402bc9f35e9707675eb427ff40f5e28d673e643132759fc5b1089ed6efcc95 is one of the transactions you're wondering about, the full message is "The ERC-20 Token Transfer might have Failed (ErrCode: unable to locate corresponding Transfer event log), check with sender."

You passed a `_to` address of 0 and a `_value` of 0. From the code:

```
if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
    ...
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
} else { return false; }
```

So no `Transfer` event is fired unless `_value > 0`, which it isn't.

I assume you didn't really mean to pass 0s as the parameters, so check the code/tool you're using to create the transaction and fix the issue there.

Comment: thanks.. but how do I have to update this code to just send the all tokens to the creator address?? that's all I want....

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In the constructor, all tokens are already assigned to the address that created the contract.

Comment: oh., sorry.. I did not see the token balance till I add this custom token to my Metamask... thanks anyway..